# Why are strings in C declared with 'const'?

Tags: c, string, pointers, constants

For example, why not:

```
char *s= "example";
```

instead of:

```
const char *s= "example";
```

I understand that const makes it unchangeable, but why do I receive an error when compiling the first?

Additionally, how does the concept apply to

```
int * x;
```

vs

```
const int *x;
```

I see the second used a lot more, is it good practice to use "cons int *"?

Comment: Because you can't modify string literals.

Comment: that doesn't explain why it can't be modified. Since char *s = "example" should just give an array of characters. I understand that you shouldn't, but it doesn't explain why you can't.

Comment: I don't think you get an error with the first one, it is valid.

Comment: I get the error message "initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type"

Comment: @B.Li string literals are normally in a zone of memory that gets mapped straight from disk to memory in read only mode (on Unix systems it's the rodata section of the executable). If you try to modify them you get a segfault - and rightly so, since string literals are normally shared throug the whole executable, so an accidental modification of one literal would break all its instances around the program.

Comment: Depends on the compiler and the options used. I just checked and Visual Studio 2015 happily accepts either syntax even at the highest warning level. I've seen code that actually did modify string literals (not intentionally - a bug, obviously), so the purpose of flagging that syntax is to force you to use `const` to prevent such bugs.

Comment: If you get an error on `char *s= "example";`, you're probably compiling your code as C++.

Comment: then how does one goes about using functions in string.h library? For example, strcat() has the following prototype: char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src); --Note the first parameter and the return vales are both of the type char *, not const char *.

Comment: Simple: You don't pass a `const` pointer as `dest`. You can pass a `const` as `src` but not `dest`.

Comment: @B.Li That's correct. You can't pass a string literal as the first parameter and you can't get one as a return value. If you did pass a string literal as the first parameter your program would crash. (on any modern operating system)

Comment: @immibis It wouldn't necessarily crash. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no requirement to use `const`, but it's a good idea.

In C, a string literal is an expression of type `char[N]`, where `N` is the length of the string plus 1 (for the terminating `'\0'` null character). But attempting to modify the array that corresponds to the string literal has undefined behavior. Many compilers arrange for that array to be stored in read-only memory (not physical ROM, but memory that's marked read-only by the operating system). (An array expression is, in most contexts converted to a pointer expression referring to the initial element of the array object.)

It would have made more sense to make string literals `const`, but the `const` keyword did not exist in old versions of C, and it would have broken existing code. (C++ did make string literals `const`).

This:

```
char *s= "example"; /* not recommended */
```

is actually perfectly valid in C, but it's potentially dangerous. If, after this declaration, you do:

```
s[0] = 'E';
```

then you're attempting to modify the string literal, and the behavior is undefined.

This:

```
const char *s= "example"; /* recommended */
```

is also valid; the `char*` value that results from evaluating the string literal is safely and quietly converted to `const char*`. And it's generally better than the first version because it lets the compiler warn you if you attempt to modify the string literal (it's better to catch errors at compile time than at run time).

If you get an error on your first example, then it's likely that you're inadvertently compiling your code as C++ rather than as C -- or that you're using gcc's `-Wwrite-strings` option or something similar. (`-Wwrite-strings` makes string literals `const`; it can improve safety, but it can also cause gcc to reject, or at least warn about, valid C code.)

Comment: It may be worth noting that given `char s1[] = "example"; char s2[] = "example";` each variable will get its own array containing the string "example", and the two copies may be independently modified, but given `char *p1 = "example"; char *p2 = "example";` both pointers might identify the *same* array; even if the memory weren't write-protected, modifying the target of one pointer might also modify the target of the other (or any other string that happens to end with some or all of the characters in "example").

Comment: Given the context of some of the string.h library functions, for example, char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src), the function that concatenates strings, wouldn't the return value and the first parameter be 'unsafe'?

Comment: @B.Li: The value returned by `strcat` is simply the value of the `dest` argument. It can be unsafe if either argument is an null or otherwise invalid pointer, or if the target array doesn't have room. There's no const-correctness problem if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @B.Li: However there are some standard C string functions, including `strchr`, that are not const-safe. You can pass it a `const char*` and get back a `char*` pointing into the same string. (C++, which includes most of the C standard library, fixes this by providing two overloaded versions, one `const` and one non-`const`.)

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio 2015 at warning level 4, this compiles and runs whether compiled as C or C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *s1= "example\n";
const char *s2= "example\n";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf(s1);  // prints "example"
    s1[2] = 'x';
    printf(s1);  // prints "exxmple"

    printf(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

If I add this line, it will fail to compile as C or C++ with every compiler I know of:

```
    s2[2] = 'x'; // produces compile error
```

This is the error the `const` keyword is designed to avoid. It simply tells the compiler not to allow assignments to the object pointed to.

It doesn't matter if your pointer points to `char` or `int` or anything else. The `const` keyword has the same effect on all pointers, and that's to make it impossible (well, very hard) to assign to the thing declared `const`.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal used as a value compiles to an array of `char` that should not be modified.  Attempting to modify it invokes undefined behavior. For historical reasons of backward compatibility, its type is `char []` although is really should be `const char []`.  You can enable extra compiler warnings to change this and instruct the compiler to consider such strings to be `const`.